# Verifying emails platform VBA

Tags: email, vba, outlook

Imagine that you have a vba code to send emails automatically but you don't know if the person who will receive your email uses Outlook or Notes. I want a code that verify if the person has Outlook or Notes.

If 'person has Outlook' then
...
If 'person has Notes' then
...
Else
"Impossible to send"
end if

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to detect receiving mail client in advance. Many users have multiple clients anyway (for example Outlook on the PC, K-9 on the Mobile Phone, Roundcube Webmail, ...), so you'd never be sure if your mail is opened on the client you expect.

If you also receive mails from these people you could parse the X-Mailer header to extract the mail client software they use, still, you'd have many cases where this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

... unless you request a receipt, and the recipient's mail client can handle this, and the recipient agrees to send this receipt... but there is no guarantee the recipient will agree (I never do!) and even if they do, this will happen after the fact, i.e. *after* you have sent your e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

The only sane way to do this is to ask them to specify in their user profile which mail client they want you to believe they will be using.  When you get their email address (how do you do this?) you could also request this information. (I am sort of assuming that you have something in your system which could be called a "user profile".)